# how to implement this code using loops in bash or python

Tags: python, bash

Below code basically prints a dot "." where Im trying to imitate a progress bar in shellscript

```
#!/bin/bash
printf "Copying files .."
sleep 1
printf "."
sleep 1
printf "."
sleep 1
printf ".."
clear
sleep 1
echo ""
echo "File copy complete"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are so many ways to write a loop.  I kind of like:

```
yes | sed 5q | while read r; do sleep 1; printf .; done; echo
```

But you really don't want a loop; you want to keep printing the progress bar until the copy finishes, so you want something like:

```
progress() { while :; do sleep 1; printf .; done; }

copy_the_files & # start the copy
copy_pid=$!      # record the pid
progress &       # start up a process to draw the progress bar
progress_pid=$!  # record the pid
wait $copy_pid   # wait for the copy to finish
kill $progress_pid  # terminate the progress bar
echo
```

or perhaps (where you should replace 'sleep 5' with commands to copy your files)

```
#!/bin/bash

copy_the_files() { sleep 5; kill -s USR1 $$; }
progress() { while :; do sleep 1; printf .; done; }
copy_the_files &
progress &
trap 'kill $!; echo' USR1
wait
```

Answer (score 2):

In Python you could do something like this:

```
from time import sleep
from sys import stdout 

Print = stdout.write
Print("Copying files..")
for x in xrange(4):
    Print(".") 
    sleep(1)
print "\nFile copy complete."
```

On each iteration it prints a new `.`

After a quick search I found this [article](http://pythoncentral.io/how-to-movecopy-a-file-or-directory-folder-with-a-progress-bar-in-python/) which gives a good explanation of how to copy a file/directory whilst updating a progress bar.

Answer (score 0):

It may help you !

```
import time

print "Copying files .."
time.sleep(1)
print "."
time.sleep(1)
print "."
time.sleep(1)
print ".."
time.sleep(1)
print ""
print "File copy complete"
```